# Docker - Uninstall Dotnet Global Tool installed through Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dotnet-tool

I am installing a dotnet tool globally through Dockerfile using the following:

```
    RUN dotnet tool install --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 3.3.0
    ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
```

I have another tool (aws sam) that tries to uninstall/reinstall the global tool internally to ensure the latest tool is installed. But it gets the error below:

```
 Failed to uninstall tool package Invalid cross-device link
```

When I try to uninstall it manually, I also get the same error.

Btw, the tools resolves just fine when I try do:

```
dotnet lambda --help
```

Comment: Here's the bug for this: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3838